# Importing Bulk user CSV file

Tags: csv, powershell, active-directory, powershell-4.0

Been trying all day to import my CSV file to my AD on Windows Server 2012.
But keep getting all kind of errors.

The error I get is this:

```
"New-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The argument is null
or empty. Provide an argument that is n ot null or empty, and then try the
command again.
At line:3 char:90
+ ... ipalname -Name $_.name -DisplayName $_.name -GivenName $_.cn -SurName $_.sn -Dep ...
+                    ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUsery
```

Can't seem to find any solution to this, so some help would be great. Here is my files.

This is my script:

```
Import-Csv .\nb1.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $userprincipalname = $_.SamAccountName + "@hirethistire.local"
    New-ADUser -SamAccountName $_.SamAccountName -UserPrincipalName $userprincipalname -Name $_.name -DisplayName $_.name -GivenName $_.cn -SurName $_.sn -Department $_.Department -Path "CN_Users,DC=HireThisTire,DC=local"-AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "Microsoft~1;" -AsPlainText -force) -Enabled $true -PasswordNeverExpires $true -PassThru
}
```

Sample Of the CSV File:

[image: CSV File]

Comment: If you're importing from a CSV and a column value for a particular row (property) is empty, then of course you will get the stated error.

Comment: But that's the thing, they aren't. Gotta say i dont have alot of experience at this.

Comment: You have a `$-.SamAccountName` in the script, should be `$_.SamAccountName`.

Comment: as i commented above, i am well aware of the spelling mistakes. i unfortunately copied the wrong file into this thread.

Comment: don't know if this has anything to do with this, but i noticed when im about to save Excel file to a CSV file, i see that there is multiple CSV file to choose between. Does this matter?

Comment: You should edit your post, and update it with the latest script and the latest error messages, and a sample of the CSV file. The only message we've got is about a spelling mistake. It will be hard to provide any help otherwise.

Comment: The post is updated.

Comment: Not an answer but its helpful when doing this type of thing in Powershell, before running the command, wrap everything in double quotes `"` this way you'll see what the command evaluates to.  Also paste the script into PowerShell's ISE and look for syntax errors.

Comment: Try spreading the script block into multiple lines, and comment out `New-ADUser `. Then add a line which does `if ($_.name -eq "" -or $_.name -eq $null) { Write-Host "name empty or null"}`. Put a breakpoint and see what $_ contains.

Comment: Just do `Import-Csv .\nb1.csv | ForEach-Object { $_.name }` and see if the names appear as you expect. My first guess is that your column heading has a space after the word, and PS is expecting that as well. `Import-Csv .\nb1.csv | ForEach-Object { $_."name " }` would get it, if so. Or save without it.